# How Can I Make images in Photoshop a Specific Size?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am a fishing lure maker and I use Photoshop to make the eyes that end up on my lures. I need the final print size of these eyes to be a certain size but I can't seem to get this right.

The process:

1. Find a stock image of a fish eye and bring it into PS.
2. Use the elliptical marquee tool to make a selection.
3. CMD + N to create a new file (from clipboard) with the dimensions of the selection.
4. On the new image: Image -> Image Size -> then I reduce the image size to meet the requirement. Usually 6-10 millimeters.

Seems to me that this should be all that is needed but the final image never prints to the required size. I have PS's native resolution to match my display size and that did not fix the issue. 2880/11.22 for my 15 inch MacBook Pro.

I really appreciate any help the community may be able to provide.

Comment: From your question I didn't understand the issue you're having: if you need an eye to be 6-8mm, you're doing it right: when you print them, they'll be 6-8mm. Why do you add your screen resolution to the mix? It doesn't matter for printing

Comment: Hi and thank you for responding! I did the screen resolution thing so that when I use the "Print Size" option under the "View" tab I see the actual print size/resolution of the image and not PS's standard resolution of 72.

It's just strange because whenever I reduce the image to the size I need it never prints in that size....

Comment: By 'actual print size' do you mean you want to have your eye to appear 6-8mm on your screen? so this have nothing to do with printing actually

Answer (score 1):

A typical resolution for print is 300dpi.

Use the Crop Tool in Photoshop, set the tool options along the top as shown below, click and drag the corner handles to make it fit the eye, then commit the crop by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Note: This will make a square image that is 6mm (0.236 inches) x 300dpi, which is 71px x 71px

[image]

To cut out the eye, use the Elliptical Marquee tool then click *Layer > Layer Mask > Reveal Selection*

[image]

When you print it, make sure you have no scaling selected in the print dialog - you may have to go into the Printer Settings for your printer to do this.  Different printers offer different options. Mine has a size option called "normal", others might say "scaling:none" or "no scaling", etc.

Comment: Good answer! I can't keep my mouth shut about how this would be better to do in a vector design application like InDesign or Illustrator though. Then you wouldn't have to think so much about numbers, you would be able to make the image exactly 6 x 6 mm (because of the resolution being in 300 pixels per *inch* this image will be 6.01 x 6.01 mm) and you will be able to place several images on one page so you don't have to waste a whole sheet every time you want to print a tiny square.

Comment: @Wolff absolutely! Of course there's no reason the OP couldn't just place the finished PSD in a page layout program to get hundreds of eyes on one sheet.

Comment: Hey all! Thank you for the awesome suggestions. After I have made the selection and revised the image I copy the image and paste it into a new A4 canvas. Then I fill that canvas with copies of the eye so it's not like I'm just printing one eye at a time. 

-Wolf I have Illustrator as well so I can give that a try. 

@Billy I will also use your method and the crop tool and see how that turns out!

Comment: Maybe you can use [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/117230/84899) about scaling a part of an image to a certain size in Illustrator/InDesign. No need to crop and scale the images before placing them.