# Is it possible to scale whole design based on a key object in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, scale

Is there a easy way to scale this "truck" based on the size of the wheeles (just for illustration purposes?

Let's just say I know that the size of the front wheele should be exactly 30cm in diameter.
Now I would like to select the whole group, then select the key element I know the size to be, and then enter the size somewhere, and have the whole design resized.

Or do I have to create an object with the size I need, and the scale it until it seems to fit right?
Or is there a more accurate way of doing this?

[image]

Comment: If you figure out the percent change of a circle to the target end state you could group all of the elements and scale it by that amount.

Comment: Select wheel, scale it then repeat the transform for all but wheel?

Comment: Or draw a line thats 15 cm out form wheel and use the scale tool to place pivot at center of wheen and drag to line

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Illustrator: How to scale precisely to a specific (off-screen) reference point?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/117189/illustrator-how-to-scale-precisely-to-a-specific-off-screen-reference-point)

Comment: I've chosen to vote to close your question as a duplicate. At first glance the question might not look similar, but check out my answer. You can use that method.

Answer (score 1):

In the example below, I have a wheel that has an original size of 45.508 units.  The target size is 30 units. A simple calculation, the target size divided by the original size *100, gives you the percentage for scaling (see screenshot below).

In Illustrator select and group all the objects, and do *Transform > Scale*, then set the scale percentage to the one you just calculated.

[image]

Comment: **Protip**: You can write the calculation into the dialog box just as long as you write one calculation at a time. So no need to leave illustrator.

Answer (score 0):

Bring the front wheel to the front of all the objects and create a clipping mask containing all the below objects. Scale the wheel to the final dimension and release the clipping mask.