# Scale an object to real dimensions using a reference line

Tags: inkscape, resize, scale

I have a reference line retrieved from a raster image in the background that I know in real life measures 10 mm (`l_ref`). I want to scale the whole picture so that everything has real dimensions.

I use the measuring instrument to get the length (`l_mes`)  then I do in my Mac shift+cmd+m scale proportionally and apply to each object separately  `100/(l_mes/l_ref)` %.

[image]
When I measure again the line has the same length, I don't understand why. Is there a better way?

Comment: HI! Maybe a picture showing before / after scaling could help us understand your issue.

Comment: @Juancho I discovered that I have to deselect the measuring tool and reselecting it. Here a gif to explain the workflow (sorry that is in italian, but the lunghezza which is lenght stay the same)

Comment: Does this answer your question?  [How do I resize line segments of a larger object to absolute values](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/153970/how-do-i-resize-line-segments-of-a-larger-object-to-absolute-values).  Your maths doesn't work out either.  It should be 10/83.27*100 to work out the percentage for scaling. After you've input it into the "width" field, you also need to hit the Apply button in the Transform dialog.

Comment: @BillyKerr thanks for the link! yes I press on apply unfortunately the gif skip that frame. Your formula is correct, but also mine.

Answer (score 1):

The transform-panel modifies objects by setting a 'transform'-attribute on the object's internal XML-element. The measure-tool, however, doesn't take this attribute into account when calculating the length, meaning it displays the length the object would have without the applied scale (this is probably a bug).

What you can do is, either use the width and height input in the toolbar to manipulate the size instead, group your object by itself before scaling with the transform-panel then ungrouping it again, or use the '[Apply Transform](https://github.com/Klowner/inkscape-applytransforms)' extension.